# How to concatenate a cast value in swift

Tags: swift, string, casting, int, concatenation

I know how to print values concatenating them inside a string, for instance:

```
var double:Double = 25.43

var double2:Double = 68.78

print("the sum of \(double) + \(double2) is equal to \(double + double2)")
```

I also know how to cast values so that I can add different types of values, like so:

```
var int:Int = 3

var double:Double = 25.43

print(int + Int(double))
```

But how do I print a sentence that has a cast value inside it?

```
var int:Int = 3

var double:Double = 25.43
```

Something like this doesn't work:

```
print("the sum of \(int) + \Int(double) is equal to \(double + double2)")
```

Thanks,

Comment: `Int(double)` is *not* a cast – it's a *conversion*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just missing one set of parenthesis:

```
var int:Int = 3

var double:Double = 25.43
var double2:Double = 68.78

print("the sum of \(int) + \(Int(double)) is equal to \(double + double2)")
```

Answer (score 2):

Any expression inside `\()` is evaluated, so to print the value of a `Double` converted to an `Int` in a string…

```
print("\(Int(double))")
```

So in your example…

```
print("the sum of \(int) + \(Int(double)) is equal to \(double + double2)")
```